# Datepicker change dateformat

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui-datepicker

How can I change date on datepicker "#to" dd.mm.yy. Now write mm/dd/yy.
If I change / with . correct calculate and id I change `(d.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + d.getDate() + '/' + d.getFullYear();` to `(d.getDate() + '/' + d.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + d.getFullYear();` not working to.

Here is code:

```
$(function () {
    $('#to').attr('disabled', true);
    $("#from").datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'dd.mm.yy',
        onSelect: function (selectedDate) {
            var x = selectedDate.split('.');
            var d = new Date(x[1] + ',' + x[0] + ',' + x[2]);
            var res = d.setDate(d.getDate() + 7);
            var dateMsg = (d.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + d.getDate() + '/' + d.getFullYear();
            $("#to").removeAttr('disabled').removeClass('hasDatepicker').datepicker({
                minDate: dateMsg
            });
        }
    });
});
```

and html:

```
<label for="from">From</label>
<input type="text" id="from" name="from" />
<br/>
<label for="to">to</label>
<input type="text" id="to" name="to" />
```

Here is all code: http://jsfiddle.net/JBrvn/4/

Answer (score 1):

why not just set the date format when the widget is initialized - also I've redesigned the solution a bit

```
$(function () {
    var dateFormat = 'dd.mm.yy';

    $("#from").datepicker({
        dateFormat: dateFormat,
        onSelect: function (selectedDate) {
            var date = $.datepicker.parseDate(dateFormat, selectedDate)
            var tod = date.setDate(date.getDate() + 7);
            $to.prop('disabled', false).datepicker( "option", "minDate", new Date(tod ));
        }
    });
    var $to = $("#to").datepicker({
        dateFormat: dateFormat
    }).prop('disabled', true);
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/2tn4A/)

Comment: Try on (http://jsfiddle.net/JBrvn/4/). Not correct calculate date. Back not correct month and year.

Comment: @NejcGalof check the updated solution.... I was planning to resdesign the solution anyway

Comment: I can't use `dateFormat: 'dd.mm.yy'` in ´$("#from").datepicker´ because don't work my other code inside. Other way?

Comment: @NejcGalof also I've made some improvements so that the todate widget is not recreated every time from date is changed

Answer (score 1):

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/JBrvn/5/)

```
$(function () {
    $('#to').attr('disabled', true);
    $("#from").datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'dd.mm.yy',
        onSelect: function (selectedDate) {
            var x = selectedDate.split('.');
            var d = new Date(x[1] + ',' + x[0] + ',' + x[2]);
            var res = d.setDate(d.getDate() + 7);
            var dateMsg = d.getDate() + '.' + (d.getMonth() + 1) + '.' + d.getFullYear();
            $("#to").removeAttr('disabled').removeClass('hasDatepicker').datepicker({
                minDate: dateMsg,
                dateFormat: 'dd.mm.yy'
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to cast the minDate property to a Date object and not a string. The string that you will get from setting the date is going to be the millisecond value and cannot be rendered by the datepicker. SO just cast the value and it should work just fine

```
$('#to').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
$("#from").datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'dd.mm.yy',
    minDate: new Date(),
    onSelect: function (selectedDate) {            
        var x = selectedDate.split('.');
        var d = new Date(x[1] + ',' + x[0] + ',' + x[2]);
        var res = d.setDate(d.getDate() + 7);
        $("#to").removeAttr('disabled').datepicker({
         dateFormat: 'dd.mm.yy',
         minDate: new Date(res)                
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: I can't use `dateFormat: 'dd.mm.yy'` in ´$("#from").datepicker´ because don't work my other code inside.